# numpy array from a heterogenous dict

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a dict like this:

```
exampledict = {0: np.array([1,2,3,4]), 1: np.array([1,2,3])}
```

What I want to do is to turn this into a numpy array. Although the shapes of two arrays in the dict are inconsistent, I am wondering, is there a way to turn this into a 2D array with padded zeros when there is not enough elements so that it looks like this:

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,0]]

The reason for this is the dict actually has many key-value pairs and I want to avoid for loops in the subsequent conputationally intensive calculations.

Thanks in advance!

- Yasir

I have tried

```
np.array(list(exampledict.values()))
```

Which failed with the error
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

a = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(exampledict, orient='index')
       .fillna(0, downcast='infer').to_numpy()
     )
```

Or with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = np.array(list(zip_longest(*exampledict.values(), fillvalue=0))).T
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 0]])
```